# SAPUI5 - Deploy application on HCP using WEB IDE w/ error on sap.ui.core.js

Tags: deployment, sapui5

So, I'm building an application in HTML 5 using SAPUI5, HANAXS and FIORI.

I have my project on a general application (called 'lccapp') at my HCP instance and now I want to deploy it into another one (called 'labscustomercenter').

**But I'm having some troubles with that.**

---

So, I have my project called: 'lccapp'.

This project has a **index.html which references to some custom css files** and to the **sap-ui-core.js** library.

When I run it locally (using WEB IDE button - ALT+F5) it runs perfectly with **NO ERROR** in the console.

But, when I deploy my project into a new application on HCP.

Here is what happen: http://prntscr.com/dusfmd

---

I've already change the reference to 'src="resources/sap-ui-core.js"' as follows and here is what happens too:

http://prntscr.com/duse3p

**How can I solve this?**

Comment: In your coding, you still have some references to “lccapp”. Is this correct?
What happens, if you try for testing:
src="https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js

Comment: Thanks, but I've already solved it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could fix it using the following method:

My application was creating the follwing URL:

*(application_name + instance_name.dispatcher.hana.ondemand.com/?hc_reset)*

So I kept the same version that was correct in the local enviroment (http://prnt.sc/dusfmd) and deployed into the application that I wanted.

Then, I added in the neo-app.json file the following property:

```
"sendWelcomeFileRedirect": true,
```

I had to configure/add this property because my welcomeFile was like this:

```
"welcomeFile": "/webapp/index.html"
```

With that, my URL could combine, finding itself, finding the needed references...

*(application_name + instance_name.dispatcher.hana.ondemand.com/webapp/index.html?hc_reset)*

Comment: Please have a look at [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and come back two days later and check as answered.

Comment: Ok, I'll. Tks!!

Answer (score 0):

Have you already tried with src="https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js"?